# Is model a reserved keyword in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reserved-words

Does anyone know if defining a rails model called "model" can be an issue?

The link that was given in a previous question seems to be broken (http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords)

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found these links:

http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/ReservedWords

http://www.yup.com/articles/2007/01/31/no-reservations-about-keywords-in-ruby-on-rails

And some others that weren't as good, and none of them state Model is a keyword.

I also just tried it out. All I did was make a scaffold and then tried out actions on the website, and everything went fine.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the two lists. I was able to successfully implement my model model.

Comment: above both links are not working.